# Using Callable instead of Supplier or vice versa

Tags: java, java-8, callable, functional-interface, supplier

I came across code that used `Callable` instead of `Supplier`. I did not see any threads spawning across to use `Callable`. But is it okay to use `Callable` instead of `Supplier`?.

One of the devs I work with stated that it does the same job. Going by the docs it doesn't but would like to know experts opinions here.

```
  Callable<Optional<NodePermissionResponse>> successHandler = () -> {
        NodePermissionResponse restResponse = response.readEntity(NodePermissionResponse.class);
        return Optional.of(restResponse);
    };

    Callable<Optional<NodePermissionResponse>> errorHandler = () -> {
        ApplicationResponse appResponse = response.readEntity(ApplicationResponse.class);
        if(appResponse.getError().getStatusCode() == NOT_FOUND_STATUS_CODE) {             
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        log.error("Fetching entitlements for group failed", appResponse.getError());                                            
        throw new ApplicationAccessException(appResponse.getError());
    };

 return processResponse(
            successHandler, errorHandler, response);
}
```

**Method to process response**

```
  public static <T> T processResponse(Callable<T> successfulResponseHandler,
                             Callable<T> unsuccesfulResponseHandler,
                             Response response) {
   //do the job here
}
```

Comment: `Callable` is just an interface. Likewise, `Supplier` is just an interface. The only difference is, `Callable.call()` is allowed to throw checked exceptions, whereas `Supplier.get()` is not.

Comment: Everything is depends on the situation, both `Callable` and `Supplier` are functional interfaces, so in some cases they are replaceable, but note that `Callable` can throw `Exception` while `Supplier` can throw only unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did not see any threads spawning across to use Callable. But is it
>   okay to use Callable instead of Supplier.

As mentioned in the comments already both `Callable` and `Supplier` are interfaces which have the same function descriptor i.e. their SAM (Single Abstract Method) are same in their signatures.

One difference being that, `Callable#call` is able to throw checked exceptions, on the other hand `Supplier#get` is not.

This means for your use case using any of them is completely acceptable, although as mentioned in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254311/what-is-the-difference-between-callablet-and-java-8s-suppliert/308337#308337)

Though both interfaces will suffice in this specific case they're intended for different purposes i.e. A Callable is "A task that returns a result" while a Supplier is "a supplier of results". The latter is more "general" in as opposed to the former.

So, the conclusion is to go with the one that most suits your specific scenario.